# getting x,y coordinates from a plotted graph and get the intersection with an other graph

Tags: matlab, graph, plot

I'm some kind of new to matlab,so the question may be elementary. I try to get the `[x,y]` coordinates of the points on a plotted graph in matlab.

The graph is simple. I already had the coordinates of some points `(xb,yb)`, and plotted the graph using `line(xb, yb)`.

Now I need to find the coordinates of all the points on the plotted lines in order to get the intersection points of these lines with another defined graph.

the code which i used is:

```
line(Xb,Yb) 
hold on
X=min(Xb):.001:max(Xb); 
y=0.03;
plot(X,y);
```

The `Xb` and `Yb` are 1*38 arrays, and shape the boundary of a region in real problem which I'm studying. But I don't have all the `x`, `Y` of the points on the boundary. I need to the intersection coordinates of the boundary with horizontal line which is plotted by `plot(X,y)`.

The `Xb` and `Yb` are:

```
 Xb = [-0.0400 -0.0550 -0.0700 -0.0850 -0.1000 -0.1000 -0.1000 -0.1000 -0.1000 -0.1000 -0.0800 -0.0600 -0.0400 -0.0200 0 0.0200 0.0400 0.0600 0.0800 0.1000 0.1000 0.1000 0.1000 0.1000 0.1000 0.0850 0.0700 0.0550 0.0400 0.0380 0.0324 0.0235 0.0124 0 -0.0124 -0.0235 -0.0324 -0.0380 -0.0400 ];'
 Yb = [0 0 0 0 0 0.0200 0.0400 0.0600 0.0800 0.1000 0.1000 0.1000 0.1000 0.1000 0.1000 0.1000 0.1000 0.1000 0.1000 0.1000 0.0800 0.0600 0.0400 0.0200 0 0 0 0 0 0.0124 0.0235 0.0324 0.0380 0.0400 0.0380 0.0324 0.0235 0.0124 0];'
```

thank you very much from your kind help.

Comment: What are the sizes of `xb` and `yb`? Can you give us a few more informations about the other graph these lines will intersect? Can you also show what you tried?

Comment: It's not a question of display, what you need is interpolation. Look at `interp1` for instance.

Answer (score 1):

If your functions are given as arrays `x1,y1` and `x2,y2`, then you can find their crossing using their linear interpolators:

```
%dummy input
x1=[0 1 2 3]; 
y1=[1 4 2 0];
x2=[-1 3 4 5];
y2=[-1 2 5 3];

x0 = (max(min(x1),min(x2))+min(max(x1),max(x2)))/2;
fun1 = @(x) interp1(x1,y1,x,'linear');
fun2 = @(x) interp1(x2,y2,x,'linear');
difffun = @(x) fun1(x)-fun2(x);
crossing = fzero(difffun,x0);
```

where your `x0` should be fairly close to the actual crossing point, I chose a point inside both of your intervals. The anonymous functions `fun1` and `fun2` create a callable function using `interp1`, which can only tell you the interpolant at specific `x` coordinates. If you have the Curve Fitting Toolbox, you can get a function in a single step using `fit`. Then `difffun` is a function given by the difference of the two input functions, the zero(s) of which will give you the crossing of the two functions. `fzero` will do just that: find a zero of a function from a given starting point.

You can run into troubles if the starting `x0` is way off, and in case of multiple zeros you will only find one at a time. In your case, the interpolating functions are not too well-behaved, so choosing a right `x0` (probably manually setting a value) is paramount.

Results with the dummy input above:

[image: plot of two functions]

output:

```
crossing =

   2.272727272727273
```

Comment: you can run the codes to the fig. which I mean. I don;t know how can I share a fig in this comment!!!! I need to the X coordinate of intersection points in fact. thank you very much in advance.

Comment: @sahar please *don't add relevant code in a comment*! Edit your question using the "edit" link below it, then everyone can see what you have. Until then: you have a plot based on `Xb,Yb`, and another one based on `X,y`, although I can see that your `y` is a single scalar. So, do you just want to catch the point where the `line` for `Xb,Yb` crosses `y=0.03`? For various values of `y`?

Comment: @ Andras Deak thank you so much. yes, it is what I need exactly.

Comment: @sahar you can just do `crossfun=@(Xb,Yb,y) fzero(@(x)interp1(Xb,Yb,x,'linear')-y,(min(Xb)+max(Xb))/2)`, which is a simplified version of the above, and you can call it as `crossingpoint=crossfun(Xb,Yb,y)` for a given line `Xb`,`Yb` and scalar `y`. ***Please delete your code-filled comments above, they are cluttering the web site.***

Comment: I just plotted your line, and it's not just a line, but a semicircle inside a square. This has 2 to 4 intersections at a given `y` value, so a very simple approach will not be possible. I mean, you won't be able to define an interpolating function based on `interp1`, since ***your line is not a function***.

Comment: @ Andras Deak thank you very much. yes, it is. So, what can I do?

Comment: @sahar you can delete your code-filled comments above, as I've already told you twice.

Comment: ok, I would. I thought that it is important to add codes to the question only.

Comment: @sahar exactly, it's important to add code to the question only, that's why I told you to add code to your question, rather than a comment:) So what do you *really* want to achieve? It feels like you're asking an XY question: you want to achieve X, but ask something related to problem Y. In other words: do you really want to find the level points of `line(Xb,Yb)`, or do you just want to determine the box around the plot? Or something like this.

Comment: @  Andras Deak I need to the X coordinates of crossing lines in varies values of Y  with the boundary which is defined by line(Xb,Yb). consider the line Y=cte, and the boundary which is defined by line(Xb,Yb), I need to the X coordinate of crossing points.