# Intersection of line and curve Matlab

Tags: matlab, intersection

Well another problem has pop up recently.
I have a set representing a curve and a line I drew with the line() function.
So far my code is :

```
clc, clear all, close all;

n = 800/1500;
I = [ 0 1.1 4 9.5 15.3 19.5 23.1 26 28.2 30.8 33.3 35.9];
E_up = [ 5.8 10.5 28 60.3 85.5 100.3 108 113.2 117 120.5 123.5 126];
E_up = E_up./n;
Iw = [ 34 31.5 28.2 23.9 19.9 16.1 13 8.1 3.5 1.2 0 NaN];
E_down = [124.6 122.5 118.8 112.2 103.9 93.1 81.6 59.1 29.6 14.5 9.5 NaN];
E_down = E_down./n;


x_est = I;
y_est = spline(Iw,E_down,x_est)
A(:,1)= E_up
A(:,2) = y_est

ma = mean(A,2)

% figure()
% hold all
% % plot(x_est,y_est,'ro')
% plot(I,E_up,'b-',Iw,E_down,'g-')
% plot(I,ma,'r')
% grid on
% legend('up','down','mean')

%dane_znamionowe

clc, clear all, close all;

%data_entry
n = 800/1500;
I = [ 0 1.1 4 9.5 15.3 19.5 23.1 26 28.2 30.8 33.3 35.9];
E_up = [ 5.8 10.5 28 60.3 85.5 100.3 108 113.2 117 120.5 123.5 126];
E_up = E_up./n; %rescalling_EMF
Iw = [ 34 31.5 28.2 23.9 19.9 16.1 13 8.1 3.5 1.2 0 NaN];
E_down = [124.6 122.5 118.8 112.2 103.9 93.1 81.6 59.1 29.6 14.5 9.5 NaN];
E_down = E_down./n; %rescalling_EMF
Un = 220;
In = 28.8;
wn = 1500;
wmax = 3000;
P = 5.5e3;
Rs = 15.8/25;

%interpolation
x_est = I;
y_est = spline(Iw,E_down,x_est);

%mean_values
A(:,1)= E_up;
A(:,2) = y_est;
ma = mean(A,2);

%party_Xd
figure()
[ax,h1,h2] = plotyy(I+30,wn,I,ma,'plot','plot');
set(ax(1),'ylim',[0 3000],'ytick',[1500  3000]);
set(ax(2),'ylim',[0 300],'ytick',[100 200 300]);
hold(ax(1))
hold(ax(2))

%stable_parts
set(ax,'NextPlot','add')
plot(ax(2),I,ma,'b')
plot(ax(2),0,Un,'m*')
i2 = 0:0.01:70;
plot(ax(2),i2,Un-(i2*Rs),'m--')
iin = 0:1:300;
plot(ax(2),In,iin,'g-')
plot(ax(1),i2,wn,'k-','linewidth',8)
plot(ax(1),28.8,1500,'g*')

%loop
p1x = [35 45 55 65];

for ii = 1 :length(p1x)
    x11 = p1x(ii);
    y11 = 0;
    x21 = In;
    y21 = wn;
    x1 = [35 45 55 65];
    y1 = [0 0 0 0];
    x2 = [In In In In];
    y2 = [wn wn wn wn];
    slope = (y21-y11)/(x21-x11);
    xLeft = 0; 
    yLeft = slope * (xLeft - x11) + y11;
    xRight = 70; 
    yRight = slope * (xRight - x11) + y11;
    plot(ax(2),x11,0,'r.')
    a1 = line([xLeft, xRight], [yLeft, yRight], 'Color', 'c');

    x0 = (max(min(x1),min(x2))+min(max(x1),max(x2)))/2;
    fun1 = @(x) interp1(x1,y1,x,'linear');
    fun2 = @(x) interp1(x2,y2,x,'linear');
    difffun = @(x) fun1(x)-fun2(x);
    crossing = fzero(difffun,x0); %crossing x coordinate
    crossval = fun1(crossing);
end
```

My graph looks like this which is pretty decent.But I need to find the intersection point of the cyan line and blue curve.

[image]

Comment: Please post only the relevant code, no one wants to read the code for the three other lines.

Comment: I suggest checking out [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33761580/getting-x-y-coordinates-from-a-plotted-graph-and-get-the-intersection-with-an-ot/33762846#33762846) to another question, which didn't solve *that* problem, but it would solve yours, I believe:)

Comment: @AndrasDeak the problem in your crossing output is that it gives out only the x coordinate whereas i need both x,y. I would be more than glad if you could craft my code to that point. Thank you anyway.

Comment: You just have to substitute into either of the interpolating functions. I added an answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

An answer based on [my solution to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33761580/getting-x-y-coordinates-from-a-plotted-graph-and-get-the-intersection-with-an-ot/33762846#33762846):

```
%dummy input
x1=[0 1 2 3]; 
y1=[1 4 2 0];
x2=[-1 3 4 5];
y2=[-1 2 5 3];

x0 = (max(min(x1),min(x2))+min(max(x1),max(x2)))/2;
fun1 = @(x) interp1(x1,y1,x,'linear','extrap');
fun2 = @(x) interp1(x2,y2,x,'linear','extrap');
difffun = @(x) fun1(x)-fun2(x);

crossing = fzero(difffun,x0); %crossing x coordinate
crossval = fun1(crossing); %substitute either function at crossing point

plot(x1,y1,'b-',x2,y2,'r-',crossing,crossval,'ks');
legend('line1','line2','crossover','location','nw');
```

after which your crossing point is given by `[crossing, crossval]`.

Result:

[image: result]

Comment: I have added the part of code that you posted and i get an error that  Interpolation requires at least two sample points in each dimension.

Comment: `p1x = [35 45 55 65];

for ii = 1 :length(p1x)
    x1 = p1x(ii);
    y1 = 0;
    x2 = In;
    y2 = wn;
    slope = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1);
    xLeft = 0; 
    yLeft = slope * (xLeft - x1) + y1;
    xRight = 70; 
    yRight = slope * (xRight - x1) + y1;
    plot(ax(2),x1,0,'r.')
    a1 = line([xLeft, xRight], [yLeft, yRight], 'Color', 'c');
    
    x0 = (max(min(x1),min(x2))+min(max(x1),max(x2)))/2;
    fun1 = @(x) interp1(x1,y1,x,'linear');
    fun2 = @(x) interp1(x2,y2,x,'linear');
    difffun = @(x) fun1(x)-fun2(x);
    crossing = fzero(difffun,x0); 
    crossval = fun1(crossing);
end`

Comment: @sayidjetzenden You need to define *vectors* `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2`. In your comment you have a single value for each. But you don't have to redefine those: just use the same variables which you use for plotting those lines......

Comment: ` x1 = [35 45 55 65];
    y1 = [0 0 0 0];
    x2 = [In In In In];
    y2 = [wn wn wn wn];`
I tried this and i get the same error.

Comment: @sayidjetzenden Have you rerun `fun1=...; fun2=...` after redefining those vectors? If so, then I find it ***highly improbable*** that you get the same error message.

Comment: well i run it inside the for loop.

Comment: @sayidjetzenden I don't see a for loop in your original code, and you don't need one for what I'm suggesting. Just define the `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2` as in your third comment above, then define `fun1`, `fun2` and compute `crossing` and `crossval`.

Comment: Well, i have updated it in order to get like 3-4 other curves as well.

Comment: @sayidjetzenden OK then. When you define an anonymous function like `fun1` or `fun2`, the workspace variables inside it are stored at the moment of definition. So if you change your `x1`, `y1` etc, you have to redefine `fun1`, `fun2`. Still, if you have 2 pairs of vectors, then you just can't get an error message saying that "you need at least two sample points". Are you sure everything is the size you assume them to be?

Comment: It seems that the loop runs only once till the fzero. The output from error is: FZERO cannot continue because user supplied function_handle ==> @(x)fun1(x)-fun2(x) failed with the error below.

 Interpolation requires at least two sample points in each dimension.

Comment: @sayidjetzenden please forget the habit of using code from answers without attribution. I suggest adding an "update" part to your question, preferably with a note saying that you're also using my solution. But in the end, Stack Overflow prefers if answers are only in actual answers, so there is no need to edit the question to contain a valid answer. That said, I know we haven't solved your problem yet.

Comment: @sayidjetzenden also, the problem is that your input to `fun2` consists of the same `x2` and `y2` values, so you have the same single point 4 times. I couldn't interpolate that either, so I understand the problems of matlab;) Supply different `x2` coordinates and you'll be more successful. But definitely read and understand my previous comment, it is very important.

Comment: x2,y2 and y1 are the intersection with the green line so they're the same. I dont need to interpolate it at that point but rather to get the intrepolation between the blue and the cyan lines.

Comment: @sayidjetzenden I don't understand that comment. My point is: use those vectors which correspond to the lines you want to compute, and only those. Anything else might and will be meaningless. Do you understand?

Comment: Well i understand but it seems that my mind is playing tricks on me, whatsoever. To make things clear; I need to get the intersection which is drawn by line() and the curve drawn by set of values (plot(I,ma)). The thing is that i cannot have any other infos about the cyan one except the intersection with green line and my random starting point.

Comment: @sayidjetzenden I don't see your problem. You should have `x1=[xLeft, xRight]; y1=[yLeft, yRight];` which is the basis of your cyan line. And `x2=I; y2=ma` for the blue line. Then use a single call to the interpolating stuff. What does not work for you in this?

Comment: Now something seems to go better but still have some NaN values at the sets abavo, i tried to 0 'em but the spline has encountered an error.
`Exiting fzero: aborting search for an interval containing a sign change
    because NaN or Inf function value encountered during search.
(Function value at -5.026 is NaN.)
Check function or try again with a different starting value.`

Comment: Your `x0` starting point is probably wrong, always use the middle of the corresponding vector `x1` or `x2`. And anyway, try allowing extrapolation to `interp1`, as in: `fun1 = @(x) interp1(x1,y1,x,'linear','extrap')` (see also my updated answer).

Comment: That's the one that definitely worked without errors except for the fact that it gives out wrong pairs.

Comment: @sayidjetzenden you don't cease to amaze me:D Please try putting together a simplified example, where you don't have all the rubbish around your current problem. If you can get it to work in a clean, minimal case, then it's easier to generalize, and you'll have more luck finding out what's wrong in the more complex case.

Comment: Heh, i can't get it working and I'm kind of desperate. I'll give it a try tomorrow with a clear mind. Anyway thanks for the long conversation we had trying to solve it. Cheers.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/HD1cCry.png?1 
That's pretty much what I have. It seems that the extrapolation works great but not along the cyan lines.

Comment: @sayidjetzenden You should also make sure that you're not confusing your axes: the `y` values can be deceiving if you confuse that. Again: I suggest a simpler example, where there is only 1 `y` axis.